# Navigation Bar Broken depending on screen size/scale/ratio

Tags: html, css

So basically I have a navbar that I want to be only a certain width. It has 4 element and I want it to be exactly the width of these elements. Here is what it looks like on my working computer.

[image]

This is exactly what I want it to look like. The navbar ends perfectly at the end of the last element and it is centered. The only way I myself was able to achieve this is by setting it a fixed width of 338px. My problem is that the navbar breaks on devices other than my own computer (eg. my phone, laptop).

[image]

I have a Fiddle here: [Fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/95up7L9e/2/)
Even in the fiddle you can see that the Twitter element ends and there is extra color after it so in this case the effect is reversed.

I do have a font but if you can find a way to get what I want with any font that would be appreciated.

Some CSS (more in fiddle):

```
    ul {
width: 338px;
list-style-type: none;
margin-left: 50%;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
transform: translate(-50%, 0);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);}
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="nav">
    <ul class="navbar">
      <li><a class='active' href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
      <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
      <li><a href='#'><span>YouTube</span></a></li>
      <li><a href='#'><span>Twitter</span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried using flexbox, I mean what browsers do you need to support (is it includes IE <= 10)?

Comment: @Konrud The only browsers i only really need to support are the ones that most people use.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the width to a fixed value caused your problem. Just remove `width: 338px;` and add `display: inline-block;`

See JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vqz208hx/

Comment: Here is what this looks like on my phone: http://nor1projects.tk/uploads/1467486903_789.png . You can see that its not what I would like it to look like. Refer to image number 1 on my post. I want it to look like that on every screen size. Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: thats a problem that your phone is causing because it's screenwidth is smaller than the width of the nav. you could adjust the font-size depending on the screensize by using css media queries.